# I need help switching back to windows

Tags: installation, windows, windows-7

I have Ubuntu 12.04 right now. For reasons I would like to switch back to windows 7. (Even though I love Ubuntu.)
I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a guide on how to do this? I do not want to keep Ubuntu. I have a flash drive and an external hard drive and I can use either or for the boot.
I would like to wipe the whole computer to use windows 7, I also have the product key for it. Any feedback is great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write "Windows PE" to a boot disk.Then,format your hard disk.Now you can install Windows 7 in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why you want to wipe instead of dual booting,

**WARNING : YOUR DATA WILL BE WIPE CLEAN , BACKUP FIRST!**

assuming you have background on installing windows, anyway the easy way:

1. prepare windows 7 cd / live usb (search google for how to do this)
2. boot using windows 7
3. when asked to format, delete your ubuntu partition and swap partition
4. format all your drive/ create partition
5. proceed as usual

summary : you only need to completely format your hdd using ntfs then install windows 7

Comment: Any links to an iso?

Comment: windows 7 iso ? well if you bought the cd you can convert from cd to iso version (check 'cd to iso' keyword in google).

Answer (score 0):

Best to use a windows Computer to format a usb-drive or at least a pen to backup your data in a way that windows can later read them.

Or - if privacy is a big pile of nerd-talk to you - put it on your cloud-space. (ubuntuone, google drive, dropbox).

Just make sure you don't wipe your drive before saving your stuff.